# Re-running failed and not-run tests in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

Let me describe a simple use-case:

Running all tests in our project may take up to 10 minutes.

Sometimes I see an obvious bug in my code after the first failed test, so I want to stop running all tests, fix the bug and re-run them. Unfortunately, I can either re-run all tests from the beginning, or re-run failed tests only.

Is there a plugin for IDEA which allows me to re-run failed tests AND tests, which weren't yet executed when I pressed "STOP"?

Comment: What if your 'fix' breaks a test that passed on the previous run?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but it can happen with "Rerun failed" button as well.

Comment: If your 'fix' breaks a test that passed on the previous run (i.e. a regression), you'd catch it the next time you ran the full test suite, which you should do before you commit your code. Giving the OP the benefit of the doubt here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlassian has the solution for your problem: [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/). But it is commercial.

Answer (score -2):

This goes against the idea of a test suite.  Normally you want to run all your tests specifically so you know you haven't broken anything somewhere unexpected.  If you change the code and then run a subset of the tests, the possibility exists that you broke something and one of the skipped tests would have failed.  This is a case of not getting your cake and eating it too.

If you find a bug in an early test, by all means stop the suite. Fix the bug but then run the suite from the beginning.